# Best way to get values using ngFormController

Tags: angularjs

This can't be correct, perhaps my google has gone off the rails but for the life of me I can't find any documentation to return all $valid = true values using the FormController. Does this functionality exist? I'm trying to marshall information from a form and send it to my web service but I wan't to make it something sensible before doing so. Currently I'm looping through all the properties in the FormController for a given form and looking to see if it doesn't start with $, and $valid = true and pushing it into an array like so:

```
            angular.forEach(form,function(data,key)
        {

            if(key.indexOf('$') === -1 && data.$valid)
            {

                var item[key] = data.$modelValue;

                clean.push(item);

            }

        })
```

Real basic, but I'm totally stumped (and can't fully believe) that this doesn't exist already in the angular API somewhere. Am I missing something? I'm still learning a lot about angular and am getting the feeling that much isn't really documented but perhaps i'm missing something quite basic. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not what `ngFormController` is used for (for validation and custom directive scripting). If you need to collection form data to send to server all you need is do is to make use of [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directives:

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="saveUser()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.email">
</form>
```

and in controller `saveUser` handler you can access form data like

```
$scope.saveUser = function() {
    console.log($scope.user); // {name: "Thomas", email: "mann@ga.com"}
    // use $scope.user data to send to server
};
```

Comment: Wow, that was totally what I needed. I guess I was running into trouble because I was using the Chrome JS debugger and the output wasn't the same as what you've shown above (though what you posted is correct). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `ng-model`. Angular won't populate the model until the value in the form is valid, so you don't need to check `$valid` manually.

Ex:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myData" ng-minlength="3" required>
{{myData}}
```

You'll see `myData` isn't populated until you've entered at least 3 characters.